# Observing argument type mismatch Spring Amqp Remoting With Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, kotlin, spring-amqp, spring-remoting

Though there is exactly 1 parameter for Service i am always hitting argument mismatch when using spring with kotlin combination.
i have also debugged
`org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke` method
i could see it is passing exactly 1 argument and correct targetObject. But `invoke(targetObject, this.arguments);`  resulted in parameter mismatch.

**Source Code:**

https://github.com/c-nnooka/RabbitMqRemotingKotlin

**Exception**

```
Caused by: **java.lang.Throwable: argument type mismatch**
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:215) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:39) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.remoting.service.AmqpInvokerServiceExporter.onMessage(AmqpInvokerServiceExporter.java:80) ~[spring-amqp-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1457) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:785) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:769) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1010) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationUtils.fillInClientStackTraceIfPossible(RemoteInvocationUtils.java:45) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationResult.recreate(RemoteInvocationResult.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.remoting.client.AmqpClientInterceptor.invoke(AmqpClientInterceptor.java:78) ~[spring-amqp-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.findJobById(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

**Interface Details:**

```
interface IJobQueryService{

    fun findJobById(args : QueryJobArgs) : QueryJobResponse

}

interface IJobService : IJobQueryService
```

**Service Implementation Details:**

```
class JobController(val jobQueryService: IJobQueryService) : IJobService{


    override fun findJobById(args: QueryJobArgs): QueryJobResponse {
        return jobQueryService.findJobById(args)
    }


}
```

**BeanConfiguration:** (Note: Not specifying complete configuration for simplicity)

```
    @Bean
    fun rmsExporter(rabbitTemplate: RabbitTemplate):AmqpInvokerServiceExporter {
        val exporter = AmqpInvokerServiceExporter();
        exporter.amqpTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        exporter.service = JobController(JobQueryProvider());
        exporter.serviceInterface = IJobService::class.java
        exporter.messageConverter = producerJackson2MessageConverter()
        return exporter;
    }

    @Bean
    fun rmxProxy(rabbitTemplate: RabbitTemplate) : AmqpProxyFactoryBean {
        val proxy = AmqpProxyFactoryBean();
        proxy.amqpTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        proxy.serviceInterface = IJobService::class.java
        proxy.routingKey = "rms.webservice.api"
        return proxy;
    }
```

**Invocation Details**

```
val jobservice  = applicationContext.getBean(IJobService::class.java)

println("Remoting Is On => " +  jobservice.findJobById(QueryJobArgs().apply { job = Job().apply { id = 1 } } ))
```

Comment: Maybe you can build for us a simple project on GH to let us play and reproduce? We are not familiar with Kotlin

Comment: Sure will do that

Comment: @ArtemBilan i have attached the source code, please take a look.

Comment: Cool! Forking for local game! Will come back to you soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you try to transport JSON over the network.

Therefore an `AmqpClientInterceptor` wraps your `QueryJobArgs` into the `RemoteInvocation` object and already that one is serialized to the JSON like:

```
(Body:'{"methodName":"findJobById","parameterTypes":["com.example.rabbiitmqremoting.args.job.QueryJobArgs"],"arguments":[{"job":{"id":1,"createdBy":null}}],"attributes":null}' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=167, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])
```

Pay attention to the `__TypeId__=org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation` header. This one is used on the consumer side to deserialize a content to the `RemoteInvocation`. But since there is no an (automatic) info for the `arguments` to be deseriailized to the `QueryJobArgs` they remains as a `LinkedHashMap`. Therefore `Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: argument type mismatch`.

As a workaround I suggest you to come back to the `SimpleMessageConverter` which will use a standard Java serialization mechanism.

**UPDATE**

OK! You know I've hacked this with the JSON as well.

So, I did this:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

@PostConstruct
fun init() {
    this.objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
}
```

And injected this `objectMapper` into all the `Jackson` converters presented in your `RabbitConfig`. Now it works as expected I assume:

```
Hellow From RMS
Remoting Is On => com.example.rabbiitmqremoting.response.QueryJobResponse@151bf776
```

Also I removed all the modifications related to the `messageHandlerMethodFactory`. Doesn't look like it is involved in the RPC.
However you may need it for some other stuff. Different story though...

Comment: works perfectly, both solutions are working. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Done voted, it will be visible once i get enough reputation.